# instantiation of templates in c++

Tags: c++, templates

Correct:

```
template<typename T>
typename remove_reference<T>::type&& move(T&&d){
  return static_cast<typename remove_reference<T>::type&&>(d);
}
```

Wrong:

```
template<typename T>
T&& move(T&&d){
  return static_cast<typename remove_reference<T>::type&&>(d);
}
```

I don't understand the difference between how these template functions are instantiated . How are the return types of both the functions are different ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think about what will happen when you call the second version with different types, reference collapsing will kick in resulting in the following:

```
int a{};
move(a); // return type deduced as int& &&, i.e. int&
move(1); // return type deduced as int&& &&, i.e. int&&
```

The first version will always result in an rvalue reference type, which is what you want with `move`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a result of the [reference collapsing rules of C++11](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html).

When you have the type `T &&`:

- If `T` is `U` then you get `U &&`.
- If `T` is `U &` then you get `U & &&`, which collapses to `U &`.
- If `T` is `U &&` then you get `U && &&`, which collapses to `U &&`.

`std::remove_reference` will "remove" an lvalue reference or rvalue reference from a type, causing `T &` and `T &&` to become `T`.

So, when `T` in your case is `U &` then the return types are different:

- Your first example returns `U & &&` which is really `U &` -- not at all what we want `std::move()` to return!
- Your second example returns `U &&`.